# Web Application Exception: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: spring, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0, dropzone.js, jersey-client

I'm using jersey and spring in my application. I don't have any issue when working with any AJAX requests but i get media not supported error when uploading files. I tried several ways, but haven't find any fix for it. Wondering if anyone can help me find the root cause of the issue. Appreciate your help.

## Server side implemention

### web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.blanc.whiteboard.RestResourceApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

### resource class

```
@Path("/upload")
@POST
//@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response uploadAsset(@Context SecurityContext sc,
        MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    User user = loadUserFromSecurityContext(sc);
    MultipartFile file = null;
    // 1. build an iterator
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    // 2. get each file
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        // 2.1 get next MultipartFile
        file = request.getFile(itr.next());
        if (file == null) {
            throw new FileUploadException("File is null.");
        }
        LOG.info(file.getOriginalFilename() + " uploaded! " + files.size());
        // 2.2 if files > 10 remove the first from list
        if (files.size() > 10)
            files.pop();

    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

### pom.xml

```
    <jersey.version>2.20</jersey.version>
   .....
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- File upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

## Error :

```
Aug 12, 2015 7:21:58 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 4 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-8080-exec-5
4 < 200
4 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, x-requested-with, Authorization, Cache-Control
4 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
4 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
4 < Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
4 < Content-Type: application/json

Aug 12, 2015 7:22:15 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 5 * Server has received a request on thread http-bio-8080-exec-1
5 > OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/v1.0/assets/upload
5 > accept: */*
5 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
5 > accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
5 > access-control-request-headers: accept, cache-control, content-type, x-requested-with
5 > access-control-request-method: POST
5 > cache-control: no-cache
5 > connection: keep-alive
5 > host: localhost:8080
5 > origin: http://localhost:9000
5 > pragma: no-cache
5 > referer: http://localhost:9000/debug.html
5 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36

Aug 12, 2015 7:22:15 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 5 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-8080-exec-1
5 < 200
5 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, x-requested-with, Authorization, Cache-Control
5 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
5 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
5 < Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
5 < Allow: POST,OPTIONS
5 < Content-Type: application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
5 < Last-modified: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 19:22:15 EDT

Aug 12, 2015 7:22:15 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 6 * Server has received a request on thread http-bio-8080-exec-10
6 > POST http://localhost:8080/v1.0/assets/upload
6 > accept: application/json
6 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
6 > accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
6 > cache-control: no-cache
6 > connection: keep-alive
6 > content-length: 108054
6 > content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywS3v9iwIqD3NwnYt
6 > host: localhost:8080
6 > origin: http://localhost:9000
6 > pragma: no-cache
6 > referer: http://localhost:9000/debug.html
6 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
6 > x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

19:22:15.340 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO  o.b.w.r.GenericExceptionMapper - Web Application Exception: **javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type**
Aug 12, 2015 7:22:15 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 6 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-8080-exec-10
6 < 415
6 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, x-requested-with, Authorization, Cache-Control
6 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
6 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
6 < Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

On front end i'm using `[dropzone][1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just expect the request body to be parsed into arbitrary data types (i.e. `MultipartHttpServletRequest`). How it works (with Jersey and JAX-RS) is through `MessageBodyReader`s (you can read more [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6720)).

Basically, based on the `Content-Type` of the request (which is `multipart/form-data`), and the method parameter type (`MultipartHttpServletRequest`), Jersey will look through it's registry for a `MessageBodyReader` that can handle those two factors. If it can't find one, it will throw the exception you are facing and send s 415.

That being said, what you *should* do is just use the [multipart support already provided by Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart). It comes with the needed `MessageBodyReader` to handle some Jersey specific (and other common) data types for multipart data. You first need the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you need to register the feature, which you've already done by adding the feature classname in your init-param

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
        org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Then you just need to use it's components. The link I provided is give a full explanation. The most common way to use this feature is to use the `@FormDataParam` annotation for your method parameters. For example

```
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response uploadAsset(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream in) {}
```

where the `InputStream` is a particular file with the name `"file"` in the Content-Disposition.

There are a few other ways to accept files. You can include the entire multipart body, and just iterate through the parts, like you are currently doing. For example

```
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response uploadAsset(FormDataMultiPart multipart) {
    Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> map = multipart.getFields();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        for (FormDataBodyPart part: entry.getValue()) {
            InputStream in = part.getEntityAs(InputStream.class);
            String name = part.getName();
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, visit the link I provided above.

Comment: Great! I believe in your last code the method should be public Response uploadAsset(@Context SecurityContext sc,
   FormDataMultiPart multipart) throws IOException